# Swift: Prepend String character when setting an Int variable

Tags: swift

I've looked across Google and have found no answer to the below..

I'm looking to prepend a single String character to a list of numbers: A12345

In the example below I'm creating the class and when declaring an instance, setting the employeeNumber to 12345. Later on, when the property is called, I'd like it to return employeeNumber prepend with the letter p.

```
class Employee {
  var surname: String
  let forename: String
  let employeeNumber: Int {
    set {
      "p\(employeeNumber)"
    }
  }

}

let employeeOne = Employee(surname: "Jones", forename: "Tom", employeeNumber: 12345)
employeeOne.employeeNumber // returns A12345
```

I appreciate that this code might be WELL off what I should be using (i.e using a setter?).

Comment: How did you get the character? Is it Random or is there any logic to get it?

Comment: Surely you have tried something, please add your current attempt at solving this? What exactly is a "list of numbers", how is it defined?

Comment: Provide a minimal reproductible example as well as a description of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the code with an example :)

Comment: @ShedInTheGarden That's not valid swift code. You can't have a `let` computed property. Show us a *real* example. Compile, see that it actually doesn't work as you expect

Comment: @ShedInTheGarden You ask us for help on code you haven't shown us. We ask for the code. You post code that isn't your real code (because it doesn't even compile, and it doesn't exhibit the behavior you say it does). We're not saying you shouldn't be on the road, we're saying that you should at least make sure that you're asking the right question. How are we supposed to help you, without seeing the real code exhibiting the issue you're allegedly having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a function (or a computed property) that returns a String value made of the employee number prefixed by a letter:

```
struct Employee {
    var surname: String
    var forename: String
    var employeeNumber: Int

    var employeeNumberAsString: String {
        "A\(employeeNumber)"
    }
}

let employee = Employee(surname: "Jones", forename: "Tom", employeeNumber: 12345)
print(employee.employeeNumberAsString)

// prints "A12345"
```

Your employee number is an Int, you can't set it with a String, use a property that stores the number and a function to retrieve the formatted number.